# SQL server 2017 ON DELETE CASCADE question

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the code for the entire script. the only issue i have is with the FK below (see lines with `--` in front) to remove it. if I add that I get an error using a DELETE, if I only apply the 4 constraints instead of 5 I can delete from the Artist table and it deletes from the other 3 as it should. but when I add PersonalInfo with an ON DELETE CASCADE suddenly I get an error, why? I plan to remove AlbumID from all tables so that they all rely on ArtistID to be identified. Allowing me to use the same column for FK as PK.

```
 CREATE TABLE Artists
    ( ArtistName varchar(20) NOT NULL, ArtistID varchar(20) NOT NULL, NumberOfAlbumTitles varchar(10) NOT NULL, AlbumID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID))
    GO
    CREATE TABLE Sales
    ( AlbumID varchar(20) NOT NULL, CopiesSoldYTD varchar(20) NOT NULL, ArtistID varchar(20) NOT NULL, SalesTotal varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AlbumID))
    GO
    CREATE TABLE Production
    ( AlbumID varchar(20), Copies varchar(20) NOT NULL, UnitPrice varchar(10) NOT NULL, AlbumTitle varchar(20) NOT NULL, ArtistID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID))
    GO
    CREATE TABLE PersonalInfo
    ( FirstName varchar(20) NOT NULL, LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL, HomeAddress varchar(30) NOT NULL, PhoneNumber varchar(10) NOT NULL, ArtistID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID))
    GO
    CREATE TABLE PersonalInfo2
    ( City varchar(20) NOT NULL, LabelName varchar(20), PostalZip varchar(6) NOT NULL, Region varchar(30) NOT NULL, ArtistID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID))
    GO
    INSERT INTO Artists 
    VALUES ('Mr Roberts', 1, 4, 10),
    ('MC Boogie', 2, 3, 11),
    ('Singin Sam', 3, 1, 12),
    ('Avenger', 4, 2, 13)

    GO
    INSERT INTO Sales
    VALUES (10, 232 , 1, 2320),
    (11, 151, 2, 1510),
    (12, 129, 3, 1290),
    (13, 487, 4, 4870)
    GO
    INSERT INTO Production
    VALUES (10 , 500 , 10, 'Roberts 1', 1),
    (11, 700, 10, 'Time To Boogie', 2),
    (12, 250, 10, ' Dance Dance Dance', 3),
    (13, 1000, 10, 'The Revenge Of...',  4)
    GO
    INSERT INTO PersonalInfo
    VALUES ('Brad', 'Roberts' , ' 126 Somewhere Lane', 2048888888, 1),
    ('Doug', 'Boogie', '234 East bay', 9078789090, 2),
    ('Raymond', 'Disco', ' 123 Dancing Queen Blvd', 3038761234, 3),
    ('Ryan', 'Apple', '66 Berkshire Bay', 4549091212, 4)
    GO
    INSERT INTO PersonalInfo2
    VALUES ('Winnipeg', 'Ready Records', 'R2E9N8', 1, 1),
    ('Calgary','Set Records', 'R3J1M7', 2, 2),
    ('Texas', 'Go Records', '56555', 5, 3),
    ('London', 'Canadian Recordings','98887', 4, 4)
   GO
ALTER TABLE Sales
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
GO
--ALTER TABLE PersonalInfo
--ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
--GO
ALTER TABLE PersonalInfo2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE Sales
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
GO
ALTER TABLE Production
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
 ON DELETE CASCADE



    GO
    UPDATE Artists
    SET ArtistName = 'Mr. Roberts'
    WHERE ArtistID = 1
    GO
    UPDATE Production 
    SET Copies = 589, UnitPrice = 12
    WHERE AlbumID = 10
    GO
    UPDATE PersonalInfo
    SET HomeAddress = '345 Pritchard Rd', PhoneNumber = 2042341234
    WHERE ArtistID = 1
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index1
    ON dbo.Artists (ArtistID, AlbumID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index3
    ON Sales (AlbumID, ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index4
    ON Production (AlbumID, ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index5
    ON PersonalInfo2 (City, ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index6
    ON PersonalInfo (ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index7
    ON Artists (ArtistName, NumberOfAlbumTitles);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index8
    ON Production (ArtistID, AlbumID, Copies, UnitPrice);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index9
    ON Artists (AlbumID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index11
    ON Sales (ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index12
    ON Production (ArtistID)
    GO
    CREATE INDEX index13
    ON PersonalInfo2 (ArtistID);
    GO
    CREATE VIEW view1 AS
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, ArtistName, PhoneNumber, CopiesSoldYTD, SalesTotal
    FROM PersonalInfo
    INNER JOIN Sales
    ON PersonalInfo.ArtistID = Sales.ArtistID
    INNER JOIN Artists 
    ON Sales.ArtistID = Artists.ArtistID
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
    AS
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Artists.ArtistName, NumberOfAlbumTitles, Artists.ArtistID, LabelName, PhoneNumber, City, UnitPrice, CopiesSoldYTD, SalesTotal
    FROM Artists
    LEFT JOIN PersonalInfo
    ON Artists.ArtistID = PersonalInfo.ArtistID
    LEFT JOIN PersonalInfo2
    ON PersonalInfo.ArtistID = PersonalInfo2.ArtistID
    INNER JOIN Production
    ON PersonalInfo2.ArtistID = Production.ArtistID
    INNER JOIN Sales
    ON Production.ArtistID = Sales.ArtistID
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FinalProjectErrorHandling2
    AS
    BEGIN TRY  
    SELECT CopiesSoldYTD, SalesTotal
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY SalesTotal, CopiesSoldYTD
    HAVING CopiesSoldYTD > 200
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
    WHILE(ERROR_NUMBER() > 0 )
         RAISERROR ('the error was handled',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
         SELECT
     ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
    END CATCH  
    GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are missing "ON DELETE CASCADE" here

```
--ALTER TABLE PersonalInfo
--ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID) <---- Missing on delete cascade
--GO
```

Once you add that

```
ALTER TABLE PersonalInfo
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

it works as required

Comment: (facepalm) lol ive been doing so many lines of SQL over the last few days and staring at screens and screens I somehow completely missed that.... lol thank you